# How to solve equation subject to constraint in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to solve a function `f(x)=0` such that `g(x)>=0`. Is it possible to do it through matlab? I use `fsolve/fzero` function for `f(x)=0`, but sometimes, it happens that `g(x)<0` which is not suitable. I know I set constraint in optimization, but I am not sure if I can do the same thing when I simply solve for a zero. I search but no one focuses on it.

Comment: You've asked many questions here and left many questions as it is when you got an answer. Consider taking a look back to mark the most helpful answers that solve your problem as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) in each question of yours by clicking *`✔`* on the left of the answers. One answer per question can be marked as accepted. You can also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/) all the helpful answers by clicking *`▲`* on the left of the answers. This awards the volunteers some reward that they deserve for volunteering their time to solve your problems

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to solve a function f(x)=0 such that g(x)>=0. Is it possible to do it through matlab?

In general no. And it's not that Matlab cannot do it. It's that without specifying g, no human can give you a general recipe to solve your problem. You should first define what g looks like.

Otherwise [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) should be your best bet.

Comment: +1 If fmincon is applicable (impossible to tell with the very limited information the asker provides) it should solve the challenge perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific optimization problem to solve (maximize/minimize a function subject to some inequality or equality constraints) then you can do so by using the CVX tool which is a Matlab tool and can be easily installed [using CVX installation guide](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/install.html). I hope thah helps.